# Getting nice chart.js animation when adding data with unshift()?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So, chart reads data from array, it doesn't really have "id" on each data. If we add data at any place in array other than at the end, for example right at the beginning in bar graph, rest of the bars won't animate moving to the right, instead they will all either rise or drop and a new bar will be added to the end.

Is there any way to insert data at specific indexes and animate properly?

Comment: Can you add a snippet with your code and a small demo? (ej. something like JSFiddle or JSbin)

Comment: it also happened to me, when i add data using push, it will animate normally. But when i add using unshift, the chart likely to be re-render from zero. i still dont know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can read this doc https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

update data via this function

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
```